# OOP - How should this be done?

Tags: c++, oop, function

I have a class that has the following variables/members:

> First Name
>
> Last Name
>
> Age
>
> Address
> etc..

I want to create getter-methods for each of them that returns the values. This could become quite large depending on the class.

Is there a quicker or more object-oriented way that would allow me to do this just using one method? The only way I can think about is to have a method that takes a parameter of the name of the variable to be returned; however, the types for the method would change depending on if it was returning a string, int etc..

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Consider avoiding using getters and setters if possible. Saves you a lot of typing.

Comment: I agree. You shouldn't need a getter/setter for every single member, and if you do, consider using a data structure instead.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need those values outside the class? If you have code that is not in `Person` that calls 4 or 5 `Person GetWhatever()` methods and glues the strings together, stuffs commas between them and so on, move that code into `Person`. Do that enough and no code outside `Person` needs to call your getters.

Some classes are logic-free, they just hold values, and they expect outside objects to do all the work. In C++, using a struct for that makes your intention clear. If you insist that code outside `Person` needs to arbitrarily access elements of Person, it's probably a struct, not a class. If you insist it's a class, prove it by adding some actual business logic to it.

Comment: Hmm.. it might be the reverse of what you give as an example - a protocol parser class.  Still, you're right in that there would be another method, perhaps taking some buffer class as a parameter, that provides input to the parsing code inside the 'Person'.  I' for one, would occasionally like some code-completion that auto-generates setter-getter methods.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "better" way which is still object-oriented. You should define one public "getter" method for each private member variable which needs to be access outside the class. You should also define a setter method, if the variable is meant to be set from outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want easy to define setter/getter - make it on single member level. Make member template with setter/getter and define is as public element of your class:

```
template <class Type>
class Member {
public:
  Member(const T& value = T()) : value(value) {}
  void setValue(const Type& t) { value = t; }
  T getValue() const { return value; } 
private:
  T value;
};
```

Use it in your class:

```
class Person {
public:
   Member<std::string> firstName;
   Member<std::string> lastName;
   Member<std::string> address;
   Member<unsigned>    age;
};
```

And usage:

```
int main() {
   Person one;
   one.firstName.setValue("Joe");
   one.age.setValue(33);
}
```

If your need some constraints (like range checking) then define some RangeCheckingMember template. If you need the members to be dependent on each others - then make relationship between them by pointers/references.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making that parameter lookup using a template member function that takes a default value in a given type.

```
template<typename ValueType>
const ValueType& get(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& default value) {
   ...
};
```

You still have to enumerate (or otherwise list) a `KeyType` of all your values (or use `std::string` which might be fine in larger cases) and work back and forth with your storage on the `ValueType`.

So, this doesn't really help you much until you decide you need arbitrarily large or completely dynamic values.  At this point, you need to implement a map which can hold any type which requires either hideous unions or a template wrapper derived class from a common base class used in the map.

The upside to this is that a `getKeys()` method can present all of the keys available in the class -- something quite useful for dynamic GUIs and message handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library in which everything subclasses some Object class (QObject for example), you can use a `map of (string, object)` to hold all your data and then access it with:

```
Object get(string name) { return memebers[name]; }

members is std::map<std::string, Object>
```

You will need to use type casts of course.

```
Button* my_var = static_cast<Button*>(my_class.get("my_button")); 
// get returns Object
```

You can also use [Qt's property system](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Q_PROPERTY) if you use [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29). This is not standard c++, but qmake and moc work on many operating systems.

Comment: That turns C++ into a scripting language. A poor one because now you need to downcast object manually and use `object.get("member")` instead of `object.member`.

Answer (score 0):

all right.since you know what you want.

```
void get(int flag, void *return_value)
```

get the `return_value` typd casting to what you want.

thanks